# Split array into subarray based on keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like below,i want to split the array into multiple separate array based on the key.if i have N number of keys i want N number of separate array.

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [service_id] => 1
                [service_name] => te1

            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [service_id] => 2
                [service_name] => te2

            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [service_id] => 8
                [service_name] => tr2

            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [service_id] => 9
                [service_name] => tr3

            )

    )
```

Output should be like,

```
 $array1 = Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [service_id] => 1
                [service_name] => te1

            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [service_id] => 2
                [service_name] => te2

            )

    )

 $array2=  Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [service_id] => 8
                [service_name] => tr2

            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [service_id] => 9
                [service_name] => tr3

            )

    )
```

Comment: You should explain why you _think_ your application needs this behavior.  The truth is: it probably doesn't.  Using variable variables is typically a symptom of a app design that needs a rethink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the below code

```
<?php

$input = array(
    '1' => array(
        '0'=> array(
                'service_id' => 1,
                'service_name'=>'lorem'
                ),
        '1'=> array(
                'service_id' => 1,
                'service_name'=>'ipsum'
                ),
    ),
    '2' => array(
        '0'=> array(
                'service_id' => 1,
                'service_name'=>'lorem'
                ),
        '1'=> array(
                'service_id' => 1,
                'service_name'=>'ipsum'
                ),
    ),
);

foreach($input as $key => $val){    
    ${"array".$key}  = $val;// Create variables with name $array1,$array2...    

}

foreach($input as $key => $val){    
    // Will print in loop as array1 array2....
    echo '<pre>'; print_r(${"array".$key}); echo '</pre>';  
}

//Individual Prinitng array1
echo '<pre>'; print_r($array1); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using create variable like `$$test`

Ex.

```
<?php 
$test = array(
    '1' => array(
        '0'=> array(
                'service_id' => 1,
                'service_name'=>'first'
                ),
        '1'=> array(
                'service_id' => 2,
                'service_name'=>'second'
                ),
    ),
    '2' => array(
        '0'=> array(
                'service_id' => 3,
                'service_name'=>'third'
                ),
        '1'=> array(
                'service_id' => 4,
                'service_name'=>'four'
                ),
    ),
);
$name = "array";
foreach($test as $key=> $value){
$final_name = $name.$key;
$$final_name = $value;
}
echo "array1:";
print_r($array1);

echo "array2:";
print_r($array2);
```

**Output**

```
array1:Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [service_id] => 1
            [service_name] => first
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [service_id] => 2
            [service_name] => second
        )

)
array2:Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [service_id] => 3
            [service_name] => third
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [service_id] => 4
            [service_name] => four
        )

)
```

Hope this work for you.

Comment: This answer is lacking an educational explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about `${}` [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) and for your case:

```
foreach($data as $ind => $ar_obj){    
    ${"array".$ind}  = $ar_obj;  
}
```

This will create two variables `$array1` & `$array2`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [service_id] => 1
            [service_name] => lorem
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [service_id] => 2
            [service_name] => ipsum
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [service_id] => 3
            [service_name] => lorem
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [service_id] => 4
            [service_name] => ipsum
        )

)
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/VJmA2)**